# How to pass multiple paramaters in Local Passport sessions?

Tags: express, passport.js, ejs

I am trying to pass 2 returned variables from Mongoose into the 'done' field to access it from an EJS page. I had it working with 1 variable, but 2 doesn't work. I tried wrapping it in JSON and it still doesn't work. Any Help?

The code where I tried 2 variables:

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
})
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        Products.find({ OwnerEmail: user.email }).then((products) => {
            done(err, {user: user, products: products})
        })
    })
})
```

The code that works (1 variable):

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
})
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        done(err, user)
    })
})
```

I'm pretty new to passport.

Comment: Welcome to SO, When you say it doesn't work...what does it mean exactly? Are you getting any errors? if so, what does the error say? The more information you provide in your questions, the better is the chance to receive answers and help from the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `passport.deserializeUser` will add the passed object to the `req.user` property. This means that when accessing the object for the EJS template rendering you will need to traverse into `req.user` to get the expected values.

```js
ejs.render(file, { user: req.user.user, products: req.user.products });
```

To clean up the nested properties I could try using the spread syntax.

Just an example:

```js
// passport.deserializeUser
done(err, { ...user, products: products})


// Render Call
// Extract out just user data into user variable.
const user = (({ products, ...others }) => others)(req.user);
ejs.render(file, { user, products: req.user.products });
```

Comment: Probably should have added that this is being authenticated in a router. Where should I add the render line? Login route: `router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: "/dashboard",
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
        failureFlash: true
    })(req,res,next)
})
`

Comment: That looks alright to me. So after you have completed the POST to `login` and passport calls `deserializeUser`, you will have access to all the data on any route through `req.user`. So you could incorporate the ejs render into your `/dashboard` route or anywhere you would like access to the data from your database.

Comment: After looking through my code for a while, I realized I wasn't passing the new req.user.user and req.user.products to the dashboard and instead of trying to return it with passport. Thanks for the help and I'm sure to mark your question as to the solution.